# How to compare error metrics for model with and without Seasonality?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, numpy, metric

I am aiming to guage the difference in my model performance from using data *with* and *without* Sesonality removal. My approach to Seasonality removal is taking the log of the column data and then performing 1-lag Differencing. This results in the first value of the column being `NaN`, which is then removed after all columns are processed. Also, it may be important to note **both** datasets are standardized after using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()`

**Edit 1**: I have found a SO post with a very similar issue, however there are no responses. This is the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579461/inverse-differencing-of-the-prediction-data-lstm)

```py
def remove_seasonality(col, drop=False):
    # check if col is stationary, if stationary skip col.
    if stationary_test(col, test=True) is True:
        return col
    
    # if column not number, skip col
    if not np.issubdtype(col.dtype, np.number): 
        return col

    if (col < 0).any(): # check if contains neg values
        # add constant, make values positive 
        col = col + col.min()
    
    log_values = np.log(col + 1) # add 1 to avoid log(0)
    
    diff = np.diff(log_values, prepend=np.nan)
    
    if drop: 
        diff = diff.dropna()
    
    return diff
```

I am using a Tensorflow model composed with Convolutional Layers and GRU's, I am using MAE to evaluate my model performance. The problem is that the log-transform and differencing results in a much smaller magnitude of numbers, so I cannot compare the difference in datasets effect on the MAE.

I'm not sure how to rescale my predictions to be able to compare them, I don't think I can perform inverse differencing on my predictions because that operation requires the first value before Differencing - which doesn't exist.

Alternatively, Is there an appropriate metric I could use to evaluate the difference in data preprocessing without performing any rescaling?

Answer (score 0):

To find the first value to invert the differencing process, I have used the last data point from the preceding dataset, e.g for my Validation predictions, I used the last value from the Training set. This last value is plugged into this function:

```py
def invert_seasonality(seasonality_vals, last_cum_val):
    invert_vals = np.insert(seasonality_vals, 0, np.log(last_cum_val + 1)).cumsum()
    invert_vals = np.exp(invert_vals) - 1
    
    return invert_vals
```